# Convert NSInteger to Float and Vice -versa

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, nsinteger

I have basic doubt.I have to convert `float minutes =( (10.09/60 ) % 60);`
but  error is `invalid to binary expression(double to double)`.
how can I make this calculation easy..
What I am trying is firstly
`float minutes =( (10.09/60 )`
then trying to convert minutes into NSInterger to solve module (%) operation..

but how can I do this...or else suggest other solution to get this calculation..

`float minutes =( (10.09/60 ) % 60);`

Comment: If you want to maintain the float you could just use `fmodf()` which is `%` for floats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The % operator doesn't work on floating-point values. You'll have to use a function to calculate what you want. Here's the basic pseudocode of what it would look like:

B % A = B - (floor(B / A) * A)

There are also library functions which will do this for you in math.h or tgmath.h

Also, you can use:
fmod() or fmodf() from .

Comment: but a/c to you, your requirement is float not int ?

Comment: If you're doing like this, then have you think what happens to your digits after decimal. Dude, you need to consider this. :)

Comment: Check this link- http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/C/0340__math.h/fmod.htm, and for more just google...just simple...:)

Comment: float min=(10/60),fin minutes=fmodf(min,60)   ya got this one

Answer (score 2):

To use `%`, you have to use an `int`. So : `(int)(10.09)%60` should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following operations depends upon requirement

float myFloat = 3.333

```
 //for nearest small integer:
int result = (int)ceilf(myFloat );

 //for nearest big integer:
int result = (int)roundf(myFloat );

 //for nearest integer:
int result = (int)floor(myFloat);
```

//For just an integer value
int result = (int) (myFloat);